# Printing values, C

Tags: c, parsing

I am trying to print the value of a `double` and an `int`. Both are pointers because I use `sscanf` to get the information for each value. My code compiles, but I have 2 warnings. The warnings are:

```
a4Functions.c:47:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
a4Functions.c:47:9: warning: format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 5 has type ‘double *’ [-Wformat=]
```

and my code is :

```
void parser(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    FILE * songs;
    char songString[ROOM_STRING_LENGTH];
    char * theString;
    char artist[ROOM_STRING_LENGTH];
    char title[ROOM_STRING_LENGTH];
    int * lengthPointer;
    double * sizePointer;
    char type[ROOM_STRING_LENGTH];
    lengthPointer = 0;
    sizePointer = 0;

    songs = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(songs == NULL)/*returns an error if file wasnt opened*/
    {
        printf("error opening file\n");
    }
    while(fgets(songString, ROOM_STRING_LENGTH, songs) != NULL)/*gets one string at a time until fgets equals NULL*/
    {
        theString = malloc((sizeof(char)*(strlen(songString)+1)));
        strcpy(theString, songString);
        sscanf(theString, "%s,%s,%d,%lf,%s", artist, title, lengthPointer, sizePointer, type);
        printf("%s,%s,%d,%lf,%s\n", artist, title, lengthPointer, sizePointer, type);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to dereference the pointer first.

```
    printf("%s,%s,%d,%lf,%s\n", artist, title, *lengthPointer, *sizePointer, type);
```

What I would do in this case is not using pointer for both variables, but just regular variables, and use & operator in the sscanf call.

Also you need to allocate memory first before using the lengthPointer and sizePointer. And don't forget to free them after you finished.

Comment: As things stand, `sscanf` with `lengthPointer` is undefined behaviour because `lengthPointer` does not actually point to enough memory to store an `int`. Same for `sizePointer`.

Comment: @Matt McNabb: good point, I added the memory allocation on my answer, thank you. Haven't using C for a while, getting rusty :P

Answer (score 2):

Need space for the data and need to pass pointers to `sscanf()`

```
// int * lengthPointer;
int  lengthPointer;
// double * sizePointer;
double sizePointer;
...
//sscanf(theString, "%s,%s,%d,%lf,%s", artist, title, lengthPointer, sizePointer, type);
sscanf(theString, "%s,%s,%d,%lf,%s", artist, title, &lengthPointer, &sizePointer, type);

// No change
printf("%s,%s,%d,%lf,%s\n", artist, title, lengthPointer, sizePointer, type);
```

BTW: Be sure to free `theString` when you are done.

```
  free(theString);
}
```